# How to check the data fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table called 'item_list'. I want to insert some data if the product_name and batch is new, other wise want to  update. For this purpose I wrote a code given below.

```
  function add_items($productname,$price,$quantity,$batch,$pack,$expiry,$customer_name,$address,$date)
    {

        $obj=new billing();
        $p="SELECT CONCAT(product_name,batch) AS product FROM item_list";
            $product_des=$productname.$batch; 
        $res=$obj->execute($p);
        while($pro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))

        { 
        $product_name=$pro['product'];

        if($product_name==$product_des||$product_name===$product_des)
            {  
                    $q="UPDATE item_list SET quantity=quantity+$quantity WHERE product_name='$productname' and batch='$batch' ";                              $result=$obj->execute($q);
                return $res;

            }
            else
            { 
                  $q="INSERT   INTO item_list
                (product_name,price,quantity,batch,pack,expiry,vender,phone,date) VALUES 
                            ('$productname',$price,$quantity,'$batch','$pack','$expiry','$customer_name','$address','$date')";
                $res=$obj->execute($q);
                return $res; 
            }  
        }



    }
```

But it doesn't work. whats wrong with this?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It throws an error? There is no result? There is a result but it's not what's expected?

Comment: run code and print queries, then try printed queries on phpmyadmin. It'll show what is wrong.